# ZF2 Child routes for restful API

Tags: api, rest, routes, zend-framework2

I'm having some troubles setting up the routes for my restful api in zend framework2. I want to create route in this format: api-rest/wall/user_id/post[/:id].

Now this is my config file:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'api-rest' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/api-rest/wall[/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'ApiRest\Controller\Wall',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'api-rest' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/api-rest/wall/:userid/posts[/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    'userid' => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'ApiRest\Controller\Wall',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

In this configuration userid is mandatory, not optional.

- `/api-rest/wall/3/posts/2` - Post with id 2 and user with id 3
- `/api-rest/wall/3/posts` - All posts by user with id 3
- `/api-rest/wall/3` - Won't match

You may also want to take a look child route usage in [routing documentation](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html).